# Data frame code seems to stop after only solving first line?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am running the line of code below to predict values using a given formula. I am using m as a value to calculate the missing data in that specific row.

```
m <- 2
UM.Item[m,]
for (j in 1:nUsers){
  if (UM.Item[m, j] == 0) {
    UM.Item[m, j] = (ItemAverage[m] - µ) + (UserAverage[j] - µ) + µ
  }
}
UMGlobal <- UM.Item[m,]
UMGlobal
```

Ideally, I can calculate all the missing values (indicated with zeroes) at once, but right now it seems as though I can only set m to one value at a time.

In other words, I would like to do `m = 1:15` (15 being my total number of rows), but the code seems to stop after calculating the first row for some reason.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the code seems to stop after calculating the first line"? Do you mean the first line of code? Or the first row of data? (Or the 2nd row, since you seem to be fixing `m = 2` and only operating on the second row right now?)

Comment: Yes sorry. The code itself works fine, but after calculating through the first row of data, the loop seems to stop. In this case, after calculating the second row of data, the rest remain unchanged.

Comment: You need an outer loop to increment `m` the same way as you are incrementing `j`, so `for(m in 1:nrow(UM.Item)) { for (j in 1:nUsers) { ... }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, most of looping operations can be done in R in a different way compared to other programming languages. If I need to replace zeros in the position *i,j* of a p x q matrix **A**, I can generate a p x q matrix **B** with all 0's excepting desired *i,j* elements, then I can add **A** + **B**. 
I understand that for a certain constant value µ the expression:
`(ItemAverage[m] - µ) + (UserAverage[j] - µ) + µ` or 
`ItemAverage[m] + UserAverage[j] - µ` 
is "mean of row [*m*] plus mean of column [*j*] substracting µ". 
I can get means by columns and rows and use them to build a (p x q) matrix **C** having each *i,j* element as the sum of the *i-th* row and *j-th* column means. In R doing **C** - µ substracts µ to each element of **C**. And I can multiply **C** * **D** = **B** where **D** is a (p x q) matriz with all 0's excepting the (*i, j*) positions that I need to replace in the original data matrix, where I need 1's. Observe that * is the simple numeric multiplying operator. 
Now, if I test the logical expression **A** == 0, I will obtain a p x q matrix with FALSE elements and TRUE in [*i, j*] positions of interest. I need to transform such a logical matrix to 0's and 1's respectively, in order to get **D**. I cannot use data type conversion functions such as `as.integer` because matrix is coerced to a vector. But I can add 0 to obtain **D**: 
Here is the code, it can be put into a function with data and mu as the parameters

```
# artificial data
A <-matrix(sample(0:10, 15*4, replace=T), 15, 4)
A

# constant mu of the formula
mu <- 0 # can be any value

# obtaining means by columns and rows  
rmeans <- rowMeans(A)
cmeans <- colMeans(A)

# means by rows to build a matrix of ncol(A) columns 
# a kind of "cbind"
rowsM <- matrix(rmeans, nrow(A), ncol(A))
rowsM

# means by columns to build a matrix of nrow(A) rows
# A kind of "rbind"
colsM <- matrix(cmeans, ncol(A), nrow(A))
colsM
# it should be transposed to sum both 
C <- rowsM + t(colsM)  
C

# getting a matrix with all 0 and 1 where elements need to be replaced
D <- ( A == 0 ) + 0
D

new_A <- A + (C - mu) * D
new_A
#
```